# When you declare Integer i = 9 in java, is i considered to be primitive type due to autoboxing?

Tags: java, primitive-types, autoboxing

When declaring this in a class:

```
Integer i = 9;
```

It complies now due to autoboxing I believe, is `i` considered primitive data type?

Comment: No.  It's an object.

Comment: `i` is not a type, it is a variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the type of `i` is still `Integer` (the reference type) - that's how it's declared, after all. The fact that it happens to be initialized using an `int` is entirely separate from the type of the variable. The literal `9` is a value of type `int`, but it's boxed into an `Integer`.

The code is equivalent to:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(9);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is autoboxed so `i` will point to an Integer object with the value 9, not a primitive.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's a (reference to an) object instance. Due to autoboxing the primitive literal 9 is converted to an `Integer` instance and referred to by `i`.

See [5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) of the Java Language Specification (JLS):

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type... At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> If p is a value of type `int`, then boxing conversion converts `p` into a reference `r` of class and type `Integer`, such that `r.intValue() == p`

To show that `i` is not a primitive variable just assign `null` to it, that's not possible for primitive variables.

Answer (score 3):

No, `i`'s type is *not* considered primitive: it is `java.lang.Integer`, a wrapper type, autoboxed by the compiler.

What gives it a partial appearance of a primitive is the fact that Java interns small integers, so you can compare them as if they were primitives:

```
Integer a = 9;
Integer b = 9;
if (a == b) { // This evaluates to true
    ...
}
```

Normally, comparison for value equality with `==` is reserved for primitive types; you should use `a.equals(b)` for reference objects. However, the expression above also evaluates to `true`, because Java keeps an internal cache of small `Integer` wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is a wrapper class for the primitive type `int`, but with some little other features/methods, such as converting the same integer to a string. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) you have:

> The Integer class wraps a value of the primitive type int in an
>   object. An object of type Integer contains a single field whose type
>   is int. In addition, this class provides several methods for
>   converting an int to a String and a String to an int, as well as other
>   constants and methods useful when dealing with an int.

Here you have a description of the Java [wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).